# Why I'm getting undefined when I tried to access the element from nested array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested

I am trying to access the elements from multidimensional array in javascript. When I tried to access the element from the arrays inside the array with a variable I'm getting `undefined` as a result. I'm getting the result if I used number instead of variable..

```
let arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(arr[i][arr.length]);
}
```

Comment: because arr[0][3] doesn't exists (`arr.length` = 3)

Answer (score 1):

Because the length of the array is 3, and your last array index is 2. You could modify it:

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];
for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  console.log(arr[i][arr.length - 1]); // Note the -1
}
```

This will return `3, 6, 9`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access all the elements in the nested arrays you will need two for loops, one to iterate the first level and the other loop to interate the inner level.

```js
let arr = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]];

for(let i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  //looping through the outer array
  console.log(arr[i])
  for(let j=0;j< arr[i].length;j++)
  {
    //looping through the inner arrays
    console.log(arr[i][j]);
  }
  
}
```